# The ListView is showing duplicate data

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

This is how I display my ListView, I'm not sure whether this is correct method or not to showing my listview like this. The problem is my listview will have duplicate data when my "CondimentDescription" having more than one data, The following is my Code, kindly advise.
[The ListView show like this, but this is not what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cABHc.png)
[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPF0h.png)

```
public List<OrderList> getOrderList() {
            List<OrderList> OrderList = new ArrayList<OrderList>();

            try {
                String selectQuery = "select t2.Id,t2.ProductCode,t2.Price,t2.Qty,t3.Description,t4.condimentDescription from TempCS t1 \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSDetail t2 on t1.DocNo=t2.Docno\n" +
                        "left outer join mProduct t3 on t2.ProductCode=t3.Code \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSCondiment t4 on t2.SeqNo=t4.SeqNo"+
                        "where t1.DocNo=" + TablePageDocNo + "\n";

                SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            OrderList list = new OrderList();
                           list.setProductCode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProductCode")));
                            list.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price"))));
                            list.setQty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Qty")));
                            list.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Description")));
                            list.set_ID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"))));
             //this will more than 1 row in my Sqlite database  
                            list.setCondimentDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CondimentDescription")));
                                    OrderList.add(list);
                                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                            }

            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        return OrderList;
    }
```

Adapter List

```
public class  OrderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public OrderListAdapter() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ListFragmentActivity.this);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return orderlist.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listproduct1, null);
            }

            final TextView _ID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proID);
            _ID.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).get_ID());
            final String proID = _ID.getText().toString();

            final TextView ProductCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productcode);
            ProductCode.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).getProductCode());

            final TextView Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            Description.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).getDescription());

            final TextView Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        Price.setText("" + String.format("%.2f",orderlist.get(position).getPrice()));
        final Double price= Double.valueOf(Price.getText().toString());

        final TextView Qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        Qty.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).getQty());

        final TextView condimentDescription=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.condimentDescription);
        condimentDescription.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).getCondimentDescription());

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debug your code ? check how many time that data come from database or it may be comes duplicate from database. check your result

Comment: ya this is because the duplicate data  from the database, so I want to know how to solve it.

Comment: change your query then

Comment: I'm don't know how to change to the correct query, please advise.

Comment: the problem is ""left outer join TempCSCondiment t4 on t2.SeqNo=t4.SeqNo"", because my t4.condimentDescription will have more than 1 item, so this is make my listview showing duplicate

Comment: it only change by you only we can not know about your database and its schema or content of table.

Comment: so do you know how to change it or make it as 2 query?

Comment: Or can you tell me some concept about changing to the correct query?

Comment: ok then write query which return you single record first then add another queryresult

Comment: also try distinct keyword first

Comment: do you have the example to guide me? I'm don't know hot to add another queryresult.

Comment: distinct is not suitable for my case i think.

Comment: select distinct Table1.Id as Id, Table1.Name, Table2.Description from Table1
left outer join Table1Table2Map on (Table1Table2Map.Table1Id = Table1.Id)
left outer join Table2 on (Table2.Id = Table1Table2Map.Table2Id)

Comment: following your query but the result is same

Comment: ok first try single single different query then check result then try to join them

Comment: I think I should follow this " 
ok then write query which return you single record first then add another queryresult" ?

Comment: ya try to get first single record by another query and then after join it

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: just get select record from your table

Comment: yes i did it, so what is next

Comment: select distinct  t2.Id as ID,t2.ProductCode,t2.Price,t2.Qty from TempCS T1 \n" +
    "left outer join TempCSDetail t2 on t1.DocNo=t2.Docno"

Comment: select Distinct t2.Id as ID,t2.ProductCode,t2.Price,t2.Qty,t3.Description  from TempCS T1 \n" +
    "left outer join TempCSDetail t2 on t1.DocNo=t2.Docno\n"+
                        "left outer join mProduct t3 on t2.ProductCode=t3.Code "

Comment: ok i done these query, what is next

Comment: check without where first

Comment: select Distinct t2.Id as ID,t2.ProductCode,t2.Price,t2.Qty,t3.Description,t4.condimentDescription from TempCS t1 \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSDetail t2 on t1.DocNo=t2.Docno\n" +
                        "left outer join mProduct t3 on t2.ProductCode=t3.Code \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSCondiment t4 on t2.SeqNo=t4.SeqNo"

Comment: when i run last query then come out with the duplicate

Comment: this is because one product can have many CondimentDescription

Answer (score 0):

Every time you should create a new object of  OrderList in do-while loop . Remove it from top of the function .

Comment: That is the problem . Value of your object is overwritten every single time .

Comment: This is one of the mistake i did, but this still not solve my main problem yet.

Comment: Check here https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

Comment: See how custom listview is made .

Comment: what is the different of using Holder?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t2.Id as ID,t2.ProductCode,t2.Price,t2.Qty,t3.Description from TempCS t1 \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSDetail t2 on t1.DocNo=t2.Docno\n" +
                        "left outer join mProduct t3 on t2.ProductCode=t3.Code \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSCondiment t4 on t1.column_name=t4.column_name"+
                        "where t1.DocNo=" + TablePageDocNo + "\n";
```

try this

Comment: syntax error near distinct, i think can put distinct in the middle?

Comment: and what is constraints between t3 and t4 pk or fk?

Comment: there is no relationship between t3 and t4

Comment: t1.DocNo=t4.Docno

Comment: distinct t4.condimentDescription having syntax error

Comment: sorry remove it i forgot

Comment: The result is same

Comment: do you have any social media like fb so that i can chat with u easy?